# How can I check if a PyQt5 QTextLine has focus or not?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, pynput

I am using PyQt5 for a project I am working on currently, and have run into an issue. I am using the pynput module on a different thread to capture certain key clicks, but I want the thread to stop when focus is on a text box. Is there an easy way to do this or can someone help me find a solution?

Comment: See [`hasFocus()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focus-prop) to check if the line edit has focus at a specific moment. Note that if you are interested in key presses *inside* the Qt application (when any of its windows has focus), you should not use pynput, but properly implement `keyPressEvent()` on the top level widget (to capture unhandled key events) or eventually install an event filter on the application.

Comment: [QApplication.focusChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusChanged).